# Create a custom gradient with 2 shapes

Tags: android, gradient, shapes

I want to create a gradient background in Android. I've used angrytools.com to generate these two shapes. Not exactly sure how to implement them.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
android:type="linear"
android:centerX="100%" 
android:startColor="#7F000000" 
android:centerColor="#FFffffff" 
android:endColor="#FFffffff" 
android:angle="90"/>
</shape>

-------------------------------------------------
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
android:type="radial"
android:centerX="50%" 
android:centerY="50%" 
android:startColor="#7F000000" 
android:centerColor="#FFffffff" 
android:endColor="#FFffffff" 
android:gradientRadius="100"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need create 2 xml file for shape like `shape1.xml` and `shape2.xml`
and put in `drawable` folder inside `res` folder.

Then use them **As per required** by calling

`android:background="@drawable/shape1"`
or 
`android:background="@drawable/shape2"`

For more detail [See here](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/07/19/android-shapes/)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can only set one android:background parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a layer-list by create yourFile.xml in drawable folder like that

```
<item>
   <layer-list>
    <item> 
           <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:shape="rectangle" >
           <gradient 
            android:type="linear"
            android:startColor="#7F000000" 
            android:centerColor="#FFffffff" 
            android:endColor="#FFffffff" 
            android:angle="90"/>
            </shape>
      </item>
      <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient 
            android:type="radial"
            android:centerX="0.5" 
            android:centerY="0.5" 
            android:startColor="#7F000000" 
            android:centerColor="#FFffffff" 
            android:endColor="#FFffffff" 
            android:gradientRadius="100"/>
            </shape>
      </item>
   </layer-list>
</item>
```

and use it like that `android:background="@drawable/yourFile.xml"`